# Possible to "move Windows XP" to data partition using following plan and symbolic links?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, partitioning, operating-systems, symbolic-link

**Background**: I have Windows XP and Windows 7 on the same machine, on different partitions. Thus, I can perform operations on either OS while said OS is not running.

Terminology: "`XP:`", "`7:`" and "`Data:`" will be used instead of the actual partition letters, for clarity. (All partitions are on the same HD. The Data: partition has plenty of room)

**Plan**:

1. Cut and paste "**Documents and Settings**", "**Program Files**" and "**WINDOWS**" from "`XP:`" to "`Data:\Windows XP\`".
2. Make symbolic links:

   1. `XP:\Documents and Settings\->Data:\WindowsXP\Documents and Settings\`
   2. `XP:\Program Files\->Data:\WindowsXP\Program Files\`
   3. `XP:\WINDOWS\->Data:\Windows XP\WINDOWS\`.
3. Restart into XP. This, naturally, is the critical and most important step to be able to do. :)
4. ***Optional***: Shrink the `XP:` partition down to about *20 GB*, using something that will preserve the data on the partition.
5. ***Optional***: Add the saved space onto the `Data:` partition.
6. I now hopefully have Windows XP working "off the data partition", with quite a bit of "space" to install my programs, movies, music, projects and etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never tried it personally, but I'm sure 99.99% you won't be able to move the Windows directory with a Junction link.

That is because many of those files, including the kernel itself, are required at bootup, before the file system driver is even loaded.

I also see no mention of Windows 7, so I am unsure of your final result.  Are you planning to Windows 7 to use these same folders?? That would be a no go as Windows 7 uses a different format for the user profiles.

This also may play havoc with Programs in Program Files which install differently depending on whether you are installing XP or Windows 7.

Comment: +1. The bootloader has a simple NTFS driver built in, but that doesn't support advanced features like writing, let alone symbolic links.

Comment: There's also the problem that XP doesn't support symlinks, though junctions should work for the Profiles and Programs folders.

Comment: One can just edit the bootloader's configuration to move \WINDOWS, can't they?

Comment: @grawity: That is true. Forgot about that.

Comment: Windows 7 would be the platform from which I make these changes.

Comment: Junctions do not work for Documents and Settings folder. Idea disproved.